# ferret_server start problem druing the deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When do the cap deploy everything works fine except the ferret-server, while restarting server its try to stop the ferret_server  in production mode and try to start the ferret_server but it fails due to permission problem .Here is the output from my deploy file** transaction: commit

- executing `deploy:restart'
  triggering before callbacks for`deploy:restart'
- executing `ferret:stop'
- executing "cd /home/sj/reelinfo/current; script/ferret_server -e production stop || true"
  servers: ["67.23.28.171"]
  [67.23.28.171] executing command

  ** [out :: 67.23.28.171] sh: script/ferret_server: Permission denied
  command finished
- executing "chown www-data -R /home/sj/reelinfo/current/"
  servers: ["67.23.28.171"]
  [67.23.28.171] executing command
  command finished
- executing "touch /home/sj/reelinfo/current/tmp/restart.txt"
  servers: ["67.23.28.171"]
  [67.23.28.171] executing command
  command finished
  triggering after callbacks for `deploy:restart'
- executing `ferret:start'
- executing "cd /home/sj/reelinfo/current; script/ferret_server -e production start"
  servers: ["67.23.28.171"]
  [67.23.28.171] executing command

  ** [out :: 67.23.28.171] sh: script/ferret_server: Permission denied
  command finished

failed: "sh -c \"cd /home/sj/reelinfo/current; script/ferret_server -e production start\"" on 67.23.28.171

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem as well, the issue is that script/ferret_server did not have executable permissions.

I added the following deploy task to handle the permissions:

```
before "deploy:restart", "correct_ferret_server_permissions"

task :correct_ferret_server_permissions do
  run "chmod a+x #{current_path}/script/ferret_server
end
```